# Second-Order ODE - Can't find in ODE books

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question concerning the method for solving the following ODE: Let $y = f(x)$ satisfying $$\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 + x \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = 1.$$

I cannot seem to find a general method for solving such equations, at least in the standard references I have. I would be happy with a reference for this question, but an answer is also welcome. I apologise in advance if a question of this form has already been made available here.

*Side Remark:* The above equation arises in the study of collapsing Ricci-flat metrics.

Comment: Try defining a new variable $u = \frac{dy}{dx}$. At least you reduce the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=(y')^2$ then the differential equation is
$$xz'+2z=2$$
which is a first order DE.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Very easy! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: You are welcome :)